# How to extend Prestashop ajaxCall function to show tpl file content?

Tags: php, ajax, smarty, prestashop

I'm facing a problem with extending **ajaxCall** function located in *blocklayered.php*

```
$smarty->assign(
   array(
     'myVariable' => 10,
     'homeSize' => ...,
     'nb_products' => $nb_products,
      ...
));
```

In my *product-list.tpl* file i have this

```
{if isset($myVariable)} 
  {$myVariable}
{/if}
```

Then when i use blocklayered (choose one of the filter options) page is refreshed by AJAX and show the results with showing **10** that is my *myVariable* value.

**Question is:** How to show something else instead of **10** like .tpl file with other contents?

**I try also:**

```
$smarty->assign(
   array(
     'myVariable' => $my_variable,
     'homeSize' => ...,
     'nb_products' => $nb_products,
      ...
));

 ...

$my_variable = $smarty->fetch(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'my_content.tpl');
```

Without success... JSON with myVariable is empty throwing just

```
" \n    "
```

Comment: Good question. I will set up bounty for this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did all good, just in wrong sequence (or show it in wrong sequence). First you need to created variable contains template data and only then use it, like:

```
$smarty->assign('myVariable', $smarty->fetch(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'my_content.tpl')));
```

or first $myVariable = ... and then assign it to tpl variable.
In this case *myVariable* will contain content of tpl file. Of course if you want to have some other data transferred from PHP (I mean not just pure html) in *my_content.tpl*, you need to assign it first, before *fetch*